# VPS to Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration

We currently have a rented VPS with such setup:

- MySQL service (multiple databases (schemas) inside)
- Multiple JVM services (Netty based API services).

We need to be able to withstand high load peaks so we are thinking about moving to AWS. I have little experience with AWS management and have questions about it:

1. Do standalone services need to be adapted for running in AWS? If not, maybe it's still preferable?
2. Can multiple services (MySQL database + a couple API services) be running on a single computing instance? If so, is it easy enough to later move one of them to it's own computing instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do standalone services need to be adapted for running in AWS? If not,
>   maybe it's still preferable?

No, but in order to take advantage of the best AWS has to offer, you'll need migrate your MySQL data into RDS and then do some work to get your application running in an auto-scaling group behind an ELB.

> Can multiple services (MySQL database + a couple API services) be
>   running on a single computing instance?

Yes.

> If so, is it easy enough to later move one of them to it's own
>   computing instance?

Define "easy".

Don't overthink things. EC2 instances are merely virtual servers. Nothing more. You can use them in the same manner as any other VPS, but that's not going to help your scaling issue. To do that, you're going to need to buckle down and commit to learning the technologies and tools that are available to you in AWS.